# Create a simple ifElse generic UDF that works for all datatypes accepted by a DataFrame. Scala, Spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataframe

So, we got a function like this:

```
def ifThenDoubleFuncion = (cond: Boolean, eIf: Double, eElse: Double) => if(cond) eIf else eElse

def ifThenUdf = udf(ifThenDoubleFuncion)
```

I wanted this function to accept all dataTypes admited by a Spark DataFrame so I tried this:

```
def ifThenFuncion[T <: AnyVal](cond: Boolean, eIf: T, eElse: T) => if(cond) eIf                   else eElse
```

But it throw an error because DataFrame can't process a AnyVal object.

I dont want to use pattern matching due to performance. I think there is an elegant way to solve this.

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Spanish post:  http://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/29136/crear-una-udf-simple-ifthenelse-que-sea-gen%C3%A9rica-y-se-pueda-usar-en-un-datafra

Answer (score 0):

Is there a specific reason to use AnyVal or generics here? 
Why just don't use Any type if the type itself is not important:

```
def ifThenDoubleFuncion = (cond: Boolean, eIf: Any, eElse: Any) => if(cond) eIf else eElse
```

**UPD**

Ah sorry. TypeTag is required there. So:

```
def ifThenDoubleFuncion[T: TypeTag](cond: Boolean, eIf: T, eElse: T): T = if(cond) eIf else eElse
udf { ifThenDoubleFuncion }
```

The `<: AnyVal` provides the unnecessary limitation to type T.

Comment: My intention is to implement a UDF that accepts all the differents types of data that a DataFrame can.

Comment: Any or AnyVal is not accepted by the DataFrame. T: TypeTag throw the following error:

Comment: compile error: scala.reflect.api.TypeTags does not take type parameters

Comment: Yes, the point is that I cannot apply all changes of the first line of your code because udf() expects a function. But so the code Im trying now is like this.  `def ifThenDoubleFuncion[T: TypeTags] = (cond: Boolean, eIf: T, eElse: T) => if(cond) eIf else eElse

def ifThenUdf = udf(ifThenDoubleFuncion)`